# intellectual property and non disclosure agreements on artwork

Tags: legal, art

I am developing a game and would like to work with an artist. I am interested to know what other developers have done with regards to creating characters.  How does one draft up agreements that might be fair to both parties?

What I think might be good is: give the artist proper attribution and the right to display the work in portfolio, and agreement to pay the commission fee for the work, but let the game designer (the commissioner of the art) own the character and can do what he/she wants with the character in the future, including choose another artist if desired.

Just wondering how other people might have done it.

Answer (score 2):

You should look up ["work for hire."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_for_hire) It's a common contractual term that describes the agreement you're looking for. I also recommend talking to a lawyer to draw up the contract for you. Any lawyer should understand what "work for hire" means.

Comment: +1 for talk to a lawyer. If you want a contract with solid legal standing, that's the way to go.